# php html to pdf library that works under freebsd

Tags: php, pdf, html-to-pdf

i need a library that converts html to pdf and outputs the pdf file to the browser/file. I've already tried dompdf, tcpdf and mpdf. The problem is that non of them work correctly under freebsd (has to do something with reading large numbers).

Does anyone know a library that enables html to pdf conversion (with utf-8 support for different languages) and works correctly on freebsd?

Comment: Maybe online library? http://www.convertapi.com

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) for a command-line utility

Comment: In that case, I think you've eliminated the only decent options... tcPDF, domPDF and mPDF are the only three pdf libraries that I'd consider.

Comment: yes i know but the problem is they dont work correctly on freebsd due to different large integer handling :(